# Enter key twice on scriptaculous autocompleter

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, scriptaculous

The autocompleter in scriptaculous has been implemented in such a way that you need to hit the enter key **twice** in order to perform the submit action. One for selecting from or hiding the autocomplete list, and one for submitting.

How do I make the autocompleter to submit on first enter key instead?

Answer (score 0):

Create callback for `afterUpdateElement` and place form submit in the end of it.
If it wouldn't work for you do the same thing for `updateElement`.